# FFMPEG tpad on live stream causes frame drops

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using ffmpeg 4.4.1 on OSX 12.0.1 Monterey. I have an ffmpeg command that takes the output from my FaceTime Camera and splits it using filter_complex. One filter parses out JPG files at 1 FPS and saves them. The other filter pads the stream with black for 10 seconds and saves it to an MP4 file. The command works fine without `tpad` filter. When `tpad` is enabled the first 15 seconds of the video after the black screen padding run at the desired frame rate, after that the framerate slows to a crawl - around 1 FPS. Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f avfoundation -framerate 30 \
   -s "1280x720" -pix_fmt uyvy422 -t 30 -i '0' \
   -filter_complex '[0:v]split=2[split1][split2];[split1]fps=1,scale=320:240[out1];[split2]tpad=start_duration=10[out2]' \
   -map '[out1]' -update 1 output/thumbnail.jpg \
   -map '[out2]' -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 output/test.mp4
```

Filter graph for above command:
[image: Filter Graph]

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with a network stream, that was solved by setting `-thread_queue_size` to a larger value. In my case setting it to 128 for a `tpad` delay of 2 seconds was sufficient. If the value is too small, FFmpeg should be printing warnings about it.